# What would be spark-sql equivalent of dateadd (seconds) function in sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, dateadd

I want to add 10 seconds to a timestamp column in a dataframe using spark-sql. The date_add() function seems to be able to add days, but not seconds.

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-add-hours-minutes-and-seconds-to-timestamp/

Comment: You can use selectExpr - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html , to do this in PySpark and generate the new column

Comment: The earlier example worked, there was a typo in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html) along with `INTERVAL` as the example suggests [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-add-hours-minutes-and-seconds-to-timestamp/)

Comment: Doesn't work, if you want to use dynamic variable instead of static value to add/substract.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that , as the selectExpr can be extended to allow parametric driven use cases as well

Comment: I agree with @ManuBatham , its not working for  dynamic variables or parametric driven use cases.